# how to make twitter bootstrap 3 image carousel auto resize image to fit within the carousel?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issues trying to get my images to fit into the box exactly.

I want them to keep their aspect ratio, size, dimensions but fit/shrink into the carousel box.

[image]

as you can see the im missing half the image, this is because i have a set height, but i want it to auto size to fit into the carousel box if that makes sense...

[www.bollinbuild.co.uk/index.html](http://www.bollinbuild.co.uk/index.html) is where you can see the carousel in action.

each image has a greater size in dimension then the carousel so therefore i lose half the image and the quality.

the 3 images im using are;

[www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/1.jpg](http://www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/1.jpg)
 
[www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/2.jpg](http://www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/2.jpg)
[www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/3.jpg](http://www.bollinbuild.co.uk/images/3.jpg)

this is my code;

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

.item{
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

.bs-example{
    margin: 10px;
}

.slider-size {
height: 300px; /* This is your slider height */

}
.carousel {
width:80%;
margin:0 auto; /* center your carousel if other than 100% */ 
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/1.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/2.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/3.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.END CAROUSEL DIV -->
    </div><!-- /.END MYCAROUSEL DIV -->
</div><!-- /.END BSEXAMPLE -->
</div>
</div>
```

I read about putting the images as a div and as a background url rather then in  tag but im still not getting the full image to sit in the carousel.

> ```
> Replace the image with a container div using the image file as a background.
> Set width to 100% so it will expand to fill it’s container.  Set the height of the slider so it will have a consistent display regardless of the image size.
> Win
> ```

source http://parkhurstdesign.com/improved-carousels-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: nope, i want the carousel to be the size i have set it, 80% width and 300px in height. I want the images to fit inside this... but the 3 images are 600px+ in height and therefore i dont get the full image into the box. 

I want to to resize if that makes sense

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of making your images the background of a div, put them as an actual `<img/>` element within those divs and give them a height of 100% (choose height because your height will break before width since you have wide images).

This

```
<div class="slider-size">
    <img src="/images/1.jpg" style="height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Instead of this

```
 <div style="background:url(/images/1.jpg) center center; background-size:cover;" class="slider-size"></div>
```

CSS Media queries:

```
/* Mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: auto;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
         width: 80%;
    }
}

/* tablets */
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: auto;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

/* laptops */
@media (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 992px) {
    .slider-size {
         height: 200px;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 80%;
    }
}

/* desktops */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .slider-size {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .slider-size > img {
        width: 60%;
    }
}
```

Comment: this has worked, but its made the carousel tiny :? 

http://bollinbuild.co.uk/index.html

Comment: @Grovesy Also, if you want the images full-size, you can change your `.slider-size` height to be the height of your pictures. The `300px` you have set prevents the images from being "taller" than that. Doing this will prevent you from having to add a width.

Comment: sorry, but when i view it on a mobile, its really tall, ie nearly takes up all the screen on iphone4. so its like this | rather than this --

if i now put this into a col- etc would it fix this ? or is it because of the height percentage

Comment: @Grovesy It is because you have a fixed height on `.slider-size` setting it to 300px. It will stay at 300px no matter what screen size you are on. If you remove that, and let it handle the slider-size itself, then you should be fine.

Comment: @Trick12 yes i just noticed that :) i have removed it and it has worked fine, however, is there a way off forcing the media widths to auto size ie;

mobile = width 80% height auto
tablets = width 80% height auto
laptop = width 80% height 200px
desktops = width 60% height 300px

Comment: @Grovesy I was just about to recommend you doing that. I updated my answer to show you the media queries I believe you are looking for. Just place those into your CSS and it should work.

Comment: well you are an typing legend, I know the theory just learning the practice, this is my first website btw. Many many thanks :)

Comment: @Grovesy No problem! I hope I've helped enough for you to get it working how you'd like. Dealing with images can be a pain in responsive websites, I know from plenty of experience!

Comment: one more question, could i now apply them media query's to any other elements that i need to make look different on mobile, laptop etc?

Comment: @Grovesy Correct! Just include the CSS for those elements within the media queries, and they will take effect for those screen widths. So if you wanted to change a color in mobile, just add the color change CSS inside of the `(max-width 767px)` query.

Comment: you have have helped more than enough, im sure this post will answer a lot of other peoples issues too. I was searching for hours, thank you for your time.

Comment: awesome, thank you :D have a great day, you deserve it!

Comment: @Grovesy Thank you, and to you as well!